# Show specific data based on id

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i've developed a php page. the problem now is i wanna show only one row from the mysql table based on the id. below is the code:

session part

```
<?php 

   session_start();

   if(!isset($_SESSION['id_g'])){

  echo '<script>window.alert("Please log in to use this system.");window.location=("../psm/index3.php");</script>';
   }

   else {

     include "../psm/conn.php";

     $id_g = $_SESSION['id_g'];

     $query = "SELECT * FROM guru WHERE id_g = '$id_g' ";

     $hasil = $conn->query($query);

     $cetak = $hasil->fetch_assoc();
     extract($cetak);
   }
   ?>
```

display table part

```
<form action="review-outing.php" method="post">
<table style="border-color: #000000;">
<tbody>
<?php

$sql = " SELECT id_s, fullname_s, nric_s, hostel_s, dorm_s, class_s, id_kb, sebab_kb, tarikh_kb, status_kb, nota_kb FROM pelajar INNER JOIN keluarbandar USING (nric_s) WHERE nric_s='$nric_s'";

$verifikasi = $conn->query($sql);
$hitung = $verifikasi->num_rows;

if($hitung){
while($cetak=$verifikasi->fetch_assoc()){               
extract($cetak);
echo '
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="alt">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">ID Permohonan</td>
    <td>'.$id_kb.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">Nama Pelajar</td>
    <td>'.$fullname_s.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>No. KP Pelajar</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="nric_s" value="'.$nric_s.'" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Hostel</td>
    <td>'.$hostel_s.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Dormitori</td>
    <td>'.$dorm_s.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Kelas</td>
    <td>'.$class_s.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Tarikh Keluar ke Bandar</td>
    <td>'.$tarikh_kb.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sebab Memohon untuk Keluar ke Bandar</td>
    <td style="text-align: justify;"> '.$sebab_kb.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="status_kb" value="Diluluskan">Diluluskan
    <input type="radio" name="status_kb" value="Ditolak">Ditolak</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Catatan</td>
    <td>Sedikit ulasan atau komen guru..<br>
    <input type="text" name="nota_kb" placeholder="'.$nota_kb.'" row="2" required></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="update1" value="Kemaskini Permohonan">
    </div>
    ';
        }
         }
        else{
        echo "Tiada permohonan keluar ke bandar diterima.";
        }
        ?>
        </form>
```

It appears error as follows;

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nric_s in C:\xampp\htdocs\PSM\reviewouting.php on line 134

Tiada permohonan keluar ke bandar diterima.
```

If i remove the WHERE nric_s='$nric_s' part in the query it will display all rows in the mysql table.

Comment: Which part from "Undefined variable" you don't understand?

Comment: i dont know how to define the variable so that the page will only show specific data. sorry im self-taught newbie. still learning.

Comment: Please remove everything but the php/mysql tags. They're irrelevant to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

$nric_s has no initial value. You have to initialize what is $nric_s value.

**For example**
    $nric_s=$_POST['nameOfInput'];